# Netty, writing to channel from non-Netty thread

Tags: java, multithreading, events, netty

I'm designing a server with Netty using google protobufs. Clients connect to the server, send requests which are processed in a non-Netty worker thread (this single worker thread handles requests from all clients) and when processing is finished I want to send a response back to the originating client.

I wonder about the best way to send the response messages.

One option would be to have my Netty channel handler implement a callback interface which the worker thread can call upon completed processing of a request and in this callback method do `ChannelHandlerContext.write(...)`.

But this would lead to poor utilization of a multi-core CPU since both the processing of the requests and the encoding of the protobufs for the responses to all clients would be executed in one single thread.

Is there any way to instead in my Netty channel handler callback post a user defined event to the Netty threads and then receive this event and do the protobuf encoding for the outgoing message in a Netty thread?

I tried to use `ctx.channel().pipeline().fireUserEventTriggered`and implementing `userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt)`in my handler but I could not get it to work. Is the user event mechanism intended for this purpose? If it is, does anyone have some example code?

Comment: You could create a MessageDispatcher that works down a message queue in an own thread. The other threads will only place the message that has to be sent into the queue and don't car about any more.

Comment: Thanks Herr Derb, I'll probably do something like that, but it would probably make sense to have a small worker thread pool for sending the responses since my response messages are significantly more complex to encode than the request messages are to decode.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about that. Netty works async (until you advised it to work sync of course). As soon as you've called `ctx.write(yourMsg)` from your dispatcher, the whole encoding in your pipeline handlers will happen in an own channel thread.

Comment: @Aardvark could you possible post an answer to your own question if you got something working?