# Is fireUserEventTriggered correct way to "glue" non-netty callback-providing services with netty pipline?

Tags: asynchronous, callback, netty

Good day!

Wondering if using **fireUserEventTriggered/userEventTriggered** is netty way to collaborate with callback-oriented external services while processing message in channel handlers?

I mean, if there is some "alien" service with *nonblocking(callback mechanic)* methods, is this is right way to call **ChannelHandlerContext#fireUserEventTriggered**(passing some params from callback closure) and then handle it within overloaded **ChannelInboundHandler#userEventTriggered** for continue communication within original channel where it all started.

Example for illustration

```
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

        externalServiceWithAsyncApi.doAndRegisterCallback(
            //some call that will finish later and trigger callback handler
            (callbackParam)-> 
                ctx.fireUserEventTriggered(
                    new ExternalServiceCallbackEvent(callbackParam)
                )
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
        //seems its for us to handle
        if (evt instanceof ExternalServiceCallbackEvent) {
            //some processing and answer in the original?
            ctx.channel()
                .writeAndFlush(...)
                .addListener(...);

        // let other handlers process
        } else {
            super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
        }
    }
```

Seems example with HeartbeatHandler in "Netty in Action" (in Listing 11.7) is relevant, but this part is a bit ahead from my current point of reading, so decided to ask for a help.

There is very similar question but something did not work for author and no answer [Netty, writing to channel from non-Netty thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001239/netty-writing-to-channel-from-non-netty-thread)

**UPD**

The correct way seems to call NOT

```
ctx.fireUserEventTriggered(...)
```

but

```
ctx.channel().pipeline().fireUserEventTriggered(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely something you could used for that. That said you can also just do the write directly from your callback.

Comment: Tnx for fast response! In real code callback logic is more complex - used this one just for illustration puprose.

Comment: Found that to be price fireUserEventTriggered must be called on ctx.channel().pipeline()

Comment: This depends... ctx.fireUserEventTriggered() will let the event start at the current `ChannelHandlerContext` position while `channel.pipeline().fireUserEventTriggered()` will have it start at the beginning of the pipeline.